# Git first steps - setting up repositories

Tags: git

I work in a small development office, with 7 programmers, and we're currently implementing Git version control -- we had no version control system before. Better late than never, right?

Having said that, we're thinking about implementing the following structure:

**Development server**

- Main repository - development's stable version
- Developer repositories - development repositories, one for each developer

**Testing server**

- Main repository - stable testing version. modifications are pushed from the main development repository

**Production server**

- Main repository - modifications are pushed from the main testing repository

Is this structure appropriate or am I missing the point of distributed version control systems? Can someone throw me some pointers or practical examples?

Edit1:

I appreciate all of your feedback, guys - things are clearer now. I understand that a structure like *developer repos* (local), *development (bare) repo*, *testing repo* and *production repo* would be a more logical choice and I can even see why some consider the *development repo* an unnecessary step.

I guess we'll do some tests and see which structure we like the most.
Thanks

Comment: How big is the team? How often do you release?

Comment: Why do you need a *development repository* for each developer? And why do you even need a *main repository* in the development server? Isn't the testing one enough?

Comment: @PenchoIlchev, we're 7 developers. We release as we go .. maybe 1 new feature a week for each developer.

Comment: @SamyDindane, that's why I asked if the structure was appropriate. We come from a very simple, very prone to conflicts and errors structure: development server with files shared across the developers, testing server and a production server. Now I ask, why shouldn't I need a dev rep for each developer? Isn't this how each developer can develop without interfering with the other dev's tasks?

Comment: @PedroStadler Yes, but he needs to have the repositories locally, on his own machine.

Comment: If you start, we didn't go this way, just try a GitHub account and read about how they work with pull requests. Then you get a very quick view at the way things work with git and it supports you to implement it further. Later you can always install things by yourself and integrate it. Saves lots of time and focusses on coding instead of installing and trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more or less about it. These are somethings you should note though:

- Make the "Main repository" on development server a [bare repository](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html).
- The developers don't need to have a repository for themselves on the server, but they have a copy of the main repository locally on their own computers.
- Every developer should fetch/merge from the main development repository and resolve conflicts before pushing back.
- Don't push to the test and production servers. From those repositories, fetch and merge from development and test servers respectively. This is because those repositories are not bare, and may in fact have commits of their own.
- Have one guy (or one of the developers) responsible for fetching changes from the test/production servers, merge them with the current stable and push them to the main repository. This way, bug fixes in the test server are merged back in the development.

Comment: Having a repo per developer centrally could make collaboration easier (every developer doesn't need to run their own instance) and as place for developers to back up their local repos (hard drives fail and all).

Comment: @R0MANARMY, I'm not sure if you are familiar with git, but with a decentralized VCS like git, you _have to_ have your own local copy of the main repository. It is true that they can have other copies of the repo just for collaboration on some branch other than master, they might just as well make that a branch in the main repository. So collaboration is not really an issue. This also solves the problem with backups.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, also, since branching and merging with git is so easy, you will most likely fetch/merge from the main repository and push back your changes frequently (unlike with svn for example), so you aren't in danger of losing a lot of work due to hardware failure.

Comment: I understand you have to have your own copy of the repo, but the repo is just a directory.  If you want to share it with other developers you have to have a server, either git-daemon, git-web  *(neither of which are windows friendly btw)* or direct file system access.  Giving each developer their own private(ish) remote repo means they don't have to set up their own server to collaborate.  It also helps with situations like *Oh no, my shiny new SSD no longer works, and all of my repos were on it!*.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, I absolutely don't think they should setup their own servers. What I said is that, instead of them having private repos to share with other programmers, they can have branches on the same main repo.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, of course this all depends on the size of the company. For example, if you are too many people, naming your branches on the main repo may become a problem. However, the OP claims his company is not so big.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd suggest:

- Have a bare repository on some of your servers. It's the repo that everybody would be pushing at/pulling from ; you won't work in it. You can see it as *the server* on a centralized SCM.
- There's no need to have a *development server*. Each developer will have his own copy of the repositories on his local computer.
- In the *testing server*, there will be copies of the repos. You usually won't have to push from it since all you work is done from *your* computers.
- The same thing applies for the *production server*.

Concerning the way you'll use Git, aka workflows, I suggest a basic one I have explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600402/604041).

Answer (score 0):

**Development server**

Main repository - development's stable version
Developer repositories - development repositories, one for each developer

I don't think each developer need their own repo on the server. They just need clone the repo to their own computer.

Also, not all developers should have the access to push to main repo. Only the team lead should have push access to main repo