# Git, working with two branches and two separate teams, merging both branches to master

Tags: git, svn

This is a common scenario in my company, currently using Svn:

There are two teams working on one project. One "maintenance" team working on a few bug fixes on a branch and another "support" team working on new features on another branch. The maintenance team needs to move their changes to production before the support team can finish their new features, so they finish their bug fixes and merge their branch back to trunk. After a couple of days, the support team finishes the new features and merge back to trunk as well, resolving any conflicts, if any exist.

What would be a typical workflow (and commands used) for this scenario using Git?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by solved - this is a scenario all source code management systems deal with. Either your support team pulls regularly from the maintenance branch oand reolves conflicts when they occur or they do as you describe and synch up afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My question really is: What would be a typical workflow (and commands used) for this scenario using Git?

Comment: By the way, the way you are trying to use branches is wrong. Check out this answer for more explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598262/git-workflow-with-3-branches-advice/10600402#10600402.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what the most common way is, I would do:

- maintenance merges it's changes into `master`:
  `git checkout master`
  `git merge maintenance`
- support rebases on `master`
  `git rebase master`
- support merges into `master`
  `git checkout master`
  `git merge support`

That way, `master` receives the fixes first, then the `support` team could check if their changes do clearly (i.e. without conflicts) apply and when done merge their `support` branch also into `master`.

If you're looking for a working (and popular) Git branching model:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

There, Vincent Driessen describes how he's dealing with multiple development branches, hotfixes, release branches and so on.

Comment: Perfect. So each member of the maintenance team also creates a branch from the "maintenance" branch to implement each bug fix and then merges back to the "maintenance", and the same goes for the support for each feature, right?

Comment: @vgardner: yes. That would be the way.